# onAccessibilityEvent not called at all

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api, accessibility

I am trying to implement an `AccessibilityService`. I have shared my code below.
When I turn on my accessibility service from settings menu then `onServiceConnected()` is called but `onAccessibiltyEvent()` is not called at all. Please guide me on this.

**Service Declaration in manifest file.**

```
<service
            android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
</service>
```

**XML file**

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"

    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />
```

**MyAccessibiltyService.java**

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {


    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.d(TAG,"Service Connected");

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Event Occurred");
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: event=" + event);
        AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = event.getSource();
        if (null == nodeInfo) return;


    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.d(TAG,"Accessibility Interrupted" );

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"Service Destroyed");
    }
}
```

**Please note that I have already checked all stackoverflow answers hence do not mark this as duplicate.**

Answer (score 13):

I needed to add a feedback type to the `accessibility_service_config` file to make it work.

Try to add this

```
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
```

Tested on a Nexus 6P with Android 7.1.2

Answer (score 11):

Everything in code seems correct.

Try one of these:

1. Go to Settings > Accessibility > YourApp > Disable and then Enable.
2. Reboot the device.

For me step 2 solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your `accessibility_service_config` lacks **packages** which define the apps your `AccessibilityService` wants to monitor. Add `android:packageNames="app.package.name"` in `accessibility_service_config`.

You can refer to Android developer guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html).

Eidt:

Well it seems to mean monitoring all packages if you don't supply packages names. Maybe you can try to specify a package to see if it works.

Comment: Yep Tried. No luck with that as well.

Answer (score 1):

For some devices power consumption limitation, AccessibilityService won't work properly, for example:vivo,you can try these:
Settings->Battery->Background power consumption managemwnt->the app->Hight background power usage.

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't realize I needed to both turn on talkback on the phone and then grant talkback access to my app/service.